# Cannot Send Image File (image/jpg) Using Winsock WSABUF

Tags: c++, http, buffer, winsock

I'm stuck and I need help.

I'm trying to write the correct code for sending back an image file so the web browser can render it. It can send back text/html just fine, but image/* is not working.

You can see the code and the URL is shown below.

https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/iocphttpd/blob/master/iocphttpl/SocketCompletionPortServer.cpp

What the browser is receiving is just a few bytes of image data.

I tried vector, std::string and const char* to set the values of WSABUF, but still the same few bytes are sent over.

Please let know what is the missing piece to make this one work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try base 64 encoding?

Comment: I'll read up about 64 encoding and see if that will get me moving forward. I'll post back when I get it implemented and tested.

Comment: @brian, I did read about base64 encoding, with that I copied two files (base64.h and base64.cpp) from another thread. I'll post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
PerIoData->LPBuffer = _strdup(str.c_str());
```

The `_strdup` function only copies up until the first null, so it cannot be used to copy binary data.  Consider using `malloc` and `memcpy` if you don't want to use the C++ library.

The alternate implementation (in the `false` branch) is also incorrect, because it saves the data in an object (`vc`) that goes out of scope before the I/O is completed.  You could instead do something like

```
vector<char> * vc = new vector<char>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that fixed the bug. See URL for the fixes I made. https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/iocphttpd/blob/9f1ab247e7e7dd007c9f8382701e4beaf682224f/iocphttpl/SocketCompletionPortServer.cpp